# ROS and nxt-python-2.x

Tags: nxt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are there any plans, or is there work under way, to update the ROS NXT stack to use nxt-python-2.x? I would like to make use of the new sensor support in version 2.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12638/ros-and-nxt-python-2.x/) by [Rodrigo Gutierrez](https://answers.ros.org/users/1647/rodrigo-gutierrez/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2012-01-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are no active development efforts on the nxt stack.  Unfortunately nxtpython version 2 came out shortly after our stack was developed.  If someone would like to take up the charge and do so please contact me.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-01-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1